# How can the enduser clear a DevExpress StringEdit editor?

Tags: devexpress

In the UI we have a textbox which is a DevExpress.ExpressApp.Win.Editors.StringEdit.

We set its properties as follows:

```
control.Properties.Mask.MaskType = MaskType.DateTimeAdvancingCaret;
control.Properties.DisplayFormat.FormatString = "yyyy.MM.dd";
control.Properties.DisplayFormat.FormatType = FormatType.DateTime;
```

When the textbox gets the focus it is empty. When the end user presses any key the control displays a valid date. The user modifies the date. Now how can the user empty / clear this textbox (using the keyboard)?

(Del, BackSpace does not work)

Thx

Answer (score 0):

From DevExpress [Text Editing Overview](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument581) help article:
`All common text editing features are available in text editors. This includes typing characters, deleting them using the BACKSPACE or DEL keys, etc. Note that end-users can press the CTRL+DEL combination to remove the editor's entire content.`

Comment: Thx for suggestion. Unfortunately CTRL+DEL does something else in my case: Depending where the caret position it "resets" the day to 01 or the month to 01 or the year to "00"  (which expanded to 2000)